# How do I find/make the URL to a PHP page in my extension?

Tags: add-on, control-panel, add-on-development, extension, act

If I have a control panel page and I want to submit it to a PHP page in my extensions' directory, how do I do that? What would the URL be?

Or would I instead make an `ACT` URL? If so, how do I do that on the control panel side of EE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be submitting to PHP file in system folder directly, as the system folder might be located outside of web root and so inaccessible for direct requests.

Instead you need to place those functions inside of a module and post data to `ACT` page, just like you say.
The function reference need to be added to `exp_actions` database table ([see example in the docs](http://ee2docs.com/development/modules.html#install))

Then to get URL to post to you will need code similar to this:

```
$act = ee()->db->select("action_id")->from("actions")->where("class", 'Module_name')->where('method', 'function_name')->get();
$remoteUrl = trim(ee()->config->item('site_url'), '/').'/?ACT='.$act->row('action_id');
```

Comment: Thank you. So how would I link to stylesheets and JavaScript files within my html?

Comment: Something like `ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<link type="text/css" href="'.URL_THIRD_THEMES.'module_name/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />');`

Comment: Thanks! Will that also work for the front end?

Comment: The URL_THIRD_THEMES constant will be available on front-end too, but  `ee()->cp->add_to_foot` function is control panel-only.